# How to get all the subviews of a window or view in latest SwiftUI App?

Tags: swiftui, ios13

Is there any way to get all the subviews of an UIView, like [view subviews] in SwiftUI app ?

When I try to query, Its giving me "_TtCOCV7SwiftUI11DisplayList11ViewUpdater8Platform13CGDrawingView....". I am trying to get all textfields, labels etc.

Comment: I'll upvote your question, even though I think the answer is "no". Also, consider the *deep* differences between `UIKit/AppKit` versus `SwiftUI`. Or what makes a `UIView/NSView` versus `View`. Being totally different stacks (with the driver being "pull" in the former and "push" in the latter), it feels (to me) like this... if you *re-frame* your question in a different way - maybe like *"Here's what I want (and why I need to get at the full view hierarchy), how do I do this in SwiftUI"* - you might get a better answer to your needs than you probably will as is.

Comment: In SwiftUI in fact there are no subviews and there is no view hierarchy in classical meening... there is just a functor which renders content into one view context. Reality of course is a bit different due to youth of framework and integration with UIKit, but ... it does not change the concept.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you should prefer not thinking about “getting” the views in SwiftUI. In SwiftUI your views are structs, and you should structure your data model to “drive” changes to the views.

For example, if you were thinking about disabling all text fields, you should consider having a bool value in your data model that “drives” your SwiftUI views to become disabled or enabled. If you were thinking about styling all text fields a certain way, you should consider storing that styling information in your data model, and use different view modifiers on the text fields when the data model’s value changes.

With that said, you *can* use UIKit methods to get all the views in your SwiftUI hierarchy, by wrapping your top-most SwiftUI view in a UIHostingController. This way, you can query some UIKit views rendered under the hood. You might not always get the views you you want, because only some views in SwiftUI are rendered using native views like UIView and NSView, and some others are not. You can use the View Debugger to inspect your view hierarchy in more details to see which views you can query.